# POST from external source

Tags: nodes, services, http-request

I have external site that needs to POST my drupal site (it basically shares data). I need to take the POST data parse it and create a node from it. Is this possible? I have created a PHP file `take_post.php` this file receives the POST request, parses it creates a node object and then sends it to `http://api/v1/node` this works fine, though it seems a little long winded?

My problem is that if a post is deleted from the external system a DELETE request is send via HTTP, however the external system has no idea of what the node ID is, and at the point of delete niether do. Is there a way to delete a node without knowing it's NID, maybe via a custom field value?

Comment: Yep, add a custom field, make sure your external API populates it with an ID it tracks, then create a custom rest resource to find and subsequently delete the content by that field value

Answer (score 0):

The UUID field is what you are looking for. It stands for Universal Unique ID.

> The UUID is guaranteed to be unique and can be used to identify an entity across multiple systems.

-- from [Entity::uuid](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Auuid)

Comment: There external service has no knowledge of the UUID though, it basically sends the same data as POST but as a DELETE request. I need a way to delete the correct node without initially knowing the UUID